# How do simple calculating with multiplication only

Tags: java, android

i have problem with my simple calculate with only multiplication from the edittext where the user input the numbers. When user click result button, numbers that user input from edittext do multiplication and show result in textview.

```
input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

output1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_one);

output2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_two);

output3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_three);

result = (Button)findViewById(R.id.result);

result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                output1.setText(input.getText()*"2");
                output2.setText(input.getText()*"3");
                output3.setText(input.getText()*"4");
            }
}
```

`(input.getText()*"")` showing red underline. It said 'Operator * cannot be applied to android.text.editable, java.lang.String'  .

Anyone can fill my code? I m beginners :)

Comment: On the assumption of no type safety here, and its an `int` : `output1.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString()) * 2));`

Answer (score 1):

`String` can not be calculated, you need to convert into numbers in the operation, you can try:

`Integer.valueOf ("")`

Answer (score 0):

make sure the user inputs a number, use

```
android:inputType="number"
```

in the EditText attributes.

```
input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);

output1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_one);
output2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_two);
output3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.output_three);

result = (Button)findViewById(R.id.result);
result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

// storing the EditText value in a variable.
// do it in the onClick method only.
int inputVal = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());

            output1.setText(inputVal * 2);
            output2.setText(inputVal * 3);
            output3.setText(inputVal * 4);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` => `EditText`

When you use `input.getText()` you get object of `Editable` class.

If you want to get its value, you have to convert `Editable` to `String`, using `input.getText().toString()`.

Now you want to multiply the value, So you have to convert String to Integer(or relevant dataType), by `Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString())` and then multiply with your value.

Now you want to assign this updated value to `TextView`, use `String.valueOf()`.

So finally your code should be:

```
int inputVal = Integer.parseInt(input.getText().toString());
output1.setText(String.valueOf(inputVal * 2));
output2.setText(String.valueOf(inputVal * 3));
output3.setText(String.valueOf(inputVal * 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
output1.setText(Integer.valueOf(input.getText().trim())*Integer.valueOf("2"));
output2.setText(Integer.valueOf(input.getText().trim())*Integer.valueOf("3"));
output3.setText(Integer.valueOf(input.getText().trim())*Integer.valueOf("4"));
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to multiply strings. You should transform the string into numbers before multipling them.

```
result.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                 int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input.getText());
                 int inputInt_times2 = 2*inputInt;
                 int inputInt_times3 = 3*inputInt;
                 int inputInt_times4 = 4*inputInt;
                 output1.setText(inputInt_times2+"");
                 output2.setText(inputInt_times3+"");
                 output3.setText(inputInt_times4+"");
            }catch(Exception e){
                 //handle the exception here
            }

        }
 }
```

the (+"") that I added in the setText was to transform the int to String again.